# InvalidSignatureException: Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'lex'

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am trying to call the Amazon Lex APIs through curl and by doing so I am stuck with this error:

```
<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>InvalidSignatureException: Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'lex'. </Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>
```

My curl request:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bots/botname/versions/versionoralias' \
  -H 'authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxx/20171228/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-amz-date: 20171228T114646Z'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use the AWS CLI instead of cURL. Signatures will be managed for you. Trying to sign your AWS calls yourself, you're going to end in a world of pain and 403 errors.

The Lex API call you're looking for is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lex-models/get-bot.html).

See [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html) to get started with the AWS CLI.